# Add object to a dictionary in variables

Tags: ansible

I'd like to add objects to a list in variables like this

```
system_user:
  - user1
system_users: "{{ system_users | union(system_user) }}"
```

It fails with a recursion error:

```
AnsibleError: recursive loop detected in template string
```

Is there any way to solve this? I want to create a definition file for each user in `group_vars/all/` and then loop through them in a playbook. I don't want to redefine the list for every new user.

PS: There's a workaround: create variables with user names, like `system_user_otto20` but it's not elegant at all.

Comment: Good question. But just to make sure, you mean `list`, not `dictionary`, right? Because if you had a dictionary/hash, things might be easier since you simply could set [`hash_behavior: merge`](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour) or use this action plugin I once have written: https://gist.github.com/udondan/b730206056a018cf9838

Comment: Well, it's going to be a list of dictionaries. I've tried ```hash_behavior: merge```, it didn't help. Do you have a working example for a merge?

Comment: The problem there then is, the list would not be merged but overridden. Only hashes can be merged, both with `hash_behavior: merge` and the linked plugin. If you can convert `system_users` itself to be a dict it should work.

Comment: Why not just loop over those two lists using `with_flattened` http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html#flattening-a-list ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar opened issue: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17906

I suggest you not to use undefined variables in template strings to define them.

As another workaround you could use hash_behaviour=merge with following definitions:
group_vars/all.yml

```
system_users:
  user1:
  user2:
```

book1.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    system_users:
      user3:
      user4:

  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ system_users | unique }}"
```

Running a playbook:

```
$ ansible-playbook book1.yml 
 [WARNING]: Host file not found: /etc/ansible/hosts

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "user4", 
        "user2", 
        "user3", 
        "user1"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

unique is used to convert dictionary to unsorted list.